# How to Observe 'add to cart' multiple option of a product

Tags: magento-1.9

I am new to Magento.I have extended core module `checkout/cart` to add to cart with multiple options of product. How can I use the observer with the following event : **controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add**

My code:

`config.xml`

```
<controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add>
            <observers>
                <flycart_disable_shopping_cart_page>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>flycart/observer</class>
                    <method>cartAdd</method>
                </flycart_disable_shopping_cart_page>
            </observers> 
        </controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add>
```

file Observer.php

```
    <?php   class Custom_Flycart_Model_Observer{    
public function cartAdd(){
    // CODE Here    }
        }?>
```

How can I get multiple products in array post: This is post

[image]

I don't know how to use observers in Magento.

sorry about my english because I'm not British

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
public function observer($observer)
{
   echo '<pre>'; 
   print_r($observer->getData());
   die('dead'); 
}
```

to get all the data passed in an array.

From the array you can get your required content